# How to fix the imported .js files in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have written  simple React Native app which shall display two background on first screen which one is overlay on one another.The app runs but it showing only a blank white screen. I have imported the login.js files from './src/components/login' in the App.js files but its not showing anything in screen beside white color?

Do I need to install any other dependency to connect with imported .js files in react-native? I am using the react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.57.8 and tools for android studio 3.2.

**.src/components/login**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegister, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style = {styles.container}>
           <View style = {styles.backgroundContainer}>
              <Image style = {styles.backdrop} source = {require('../../images/vape.jpg')} resizeMode = 'cover'/>
           </View>
           <View style = { styles.overlay}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.logo}
                    source={require('../../images/smoke.jpg')}/>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Ada Smoke Shop</Text>
           </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  backgroundContainer: {
    flex:1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top:0,
    bottom:0,
    left:0,
    right:0
  },
  overlay: {
    opacity: 0.5,
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    top:100
  },
  logoContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  logo: {
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    top:150,
    left: 50,
    width: 200,
    height: 200
  },
  backdrop: {
  flex:1,

},
title: {
    color: '#B03A2E',
    marginTop:150,
    width:300,
    height:300,
    fontSize: 30,
    fontStyle: 'italic',
    fontFamily: 'Baskerville',
    textAlign: 'center',
    opacity: 10
  },
});
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegister, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';

import login from './src/components/login';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style = {styles.container}>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Login` component is imported, but not used. Your `render` in App.js should be something like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style = {styles.container}>
        <Login /> 
      </View>
    );
  }
```